# T-SQL data type analogous to List

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there anything in T-SQL that is analogous to a List data structure? Essentially I am doing an operation and for every change that is made, I'd like to make a note for the item to include in an email (msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail).

This could be for one item, or 500, it depends on what matches the criteria. Surely there has to be something better than appending a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a table variable:

```
declare @list table (OpName varchar(50), OpStartTime DateTime)

... do ops here ...

declare @mailbody varchar(max)
select  @mailbody = isnull(@mailbody,'') + 
            OpName + ' ' + convert('varchar(12), OpStartTime, 111) +
            char(13) + char(10)
from    @list
order by
        OpStartTime
```

Comment: You mean append a variable as per OP's question...?

Comment: That doesn't append, it's a direct assignment from the table. Thanks Andomar, that's about as analogous as I think I'm going to get. Cheers.

Comment: @Sam - This string concatenation technique essentially works through the table a row at a time and for each row appends to the variable so I can see gbn's point. You are still doing the string concatenation but are now also inserting to a table as well.

Answer (score 1):

No. Append a variable as you noted.

A "List" would normally be held in a relational structure, be it a table or some XML

Comment: Are strings in T-SQL (i.e. TEXT) mutable?